# Snowflake: Replace multiple patterns using single Regex_replace

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement: Want to achieve all below into one regex_replace

1. Replace comma, tab and new line character to empty
2. Replace double quotes into a single quote
3. Replace pipe into a dash

Also would like to know if `replace` performance is faster than `regex_replace`

Below is what I tried out

```sql
    with c as (select ' abc \n def\n' as t
              union 
              select 'abc\tdef' as t)          
    select t,regexp_replace(t, '[,\t\n]','') from c;
   
    with c as (select ' abc  de"f\n' as t
              union
              select 'abc\td|ef' as t)
    select t,replace(replace(replace(t, '\n',' '),'"','\''),'|','-') from c;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp_replace function will only match one pattern and replace it with a literal value, so you can't make it selectively replace depending on what it matches. You can write a UDF to do that in one step, which will make your SQL a lot neater, particularly if you have to put it in a lot of statements. This one does all three replacements:

```
create or replace function CLEANUP_STRING(STR string)
returns string
language javascript as
$$
    var s = STR.replace(/[,\t\n]/g, "");  // Replace comma, tab and new line character to empty
    s = s.replace(/"/g, "'");             // Replace double quote with single quote
    s = s.replace(/\|/g, "-");            // Replace pipe with dash
    return s;
$$;

-- This will display in black font, showing that the line break is gone.
select cleanup_string('This is a "double quoted string". This has a | pipe. This has a new \n line. This has a, comma.');
```

Comment: Thanks @Greg Pavlik , Is Replace faster than Regex_Replace .. Also I don't want to create UDF just for one query. Different query has different logic for replacement

Comment: It's hard to say without testing. JavaScript UDFs run fast. I've run them on very large tables. You have some overhead on small tables (such as testing with a single string literal), but once it's in a query they run fast. I've written JavaScript and SQL UDFs that do the same things and JavaScript are sometimes faster, especially as in this case where it would require nested replace or nested regexp_replace calls in a SQL UDF. Edit: Concerning the "different logic for replacement", you could generalize the UDF to handle different replacement rules. Just add another parameter for the rule.